# store .db file into application jar file

Tags: java-me, rms

In my j2me application, The RecordStore name is "UserAns", and the entered data is stored in the '0000003-User-Ans.db' file.
I can fetch the data from '0000003-User-Ans.db' file and display it on Emulator.
But when I run the application on device, then it can't display any data.
So, how can I add '0000003-User-Ans.db' file into Application Jar File ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecordStore` internals is device dependent. The `.db` file that works on emulator will not work  on real devices.

However, you could store your initial data in a different format, say [csv](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), for example, and have an import procedure running at the very first time the application is executed (your `RecordStore` will be empty then).

**Update after comments**

Let's say you only have one "table" to initiate: Product. With columns: id, name, price. And that there is a Product Java class with corresponding attributes. A csv sample would be

```
1, Pen, 1
2, Clip, 0.05
3, Eraser, 0.5
```

Have this content stored in a file inside the jar, for example, products.csv. Open this file and parse each line to create a Product instance. Convert each instance to a byte array and create a record entry for each of them.

Next time the application is initiated the `RecordStore` will not be empty and a Product instance can be created for each record found.

Comment: Telmo Pimentel Mota :: how can I install the application with csv file?

Comment: Telmo Pimentel Mota :: I had done according to your answer and get data from csv file and display it on device. Here, I got all added data for display from csv file. But I want to display only single cell data of csv file.So, how can I implement it?

Comment: This is the subject of another question. :)